# SQL Query to obtain result set based on inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

SQL help required.

Tables

- Person (id, name)
- Message (id, text)
- PersonMsgResponse (msgID, personID, delMethod, received(Y/N)

Structure of the PersonMsgResponse table

- MessageID (MsgId)
- PersonID  (PerID)
- MessageDeliveredBy (DelMethod)
- Received (Y/N) (Received)

Example Rows within PersonMsgResponse table

[image: Example Rows within PersonMsgResponse table]

I need to return a list of person names that did NOT receive the message.

How do I fashion the SQL to only return member names for those members that have not received the message via any of the methods?

For instance in the list of records above my query should only return member 1 since member 2 received the message by way of a phone call,  whereas member 1 has not received the message by way of either method.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with 2 inner queries like below. The trick is to include all Persons that have 'N' in received but do not have 'Y'. Message table is technically unnecessary for this example.

```
SELECT  p.Name
FROM    Person p
WHERE   p.id IN (   
                    SELECT personID 
                    FROM PersonMsgResponse pmr 
                    WHERE pmr.received = 'N' AND pmr.personID NOT IN (SELECT personID FROM PersonMsgResponse pmr WHERE pmr.received = 'Y')
                )
```

This returns

```
Name
person 1
```

Comment: This did the trick with addition of the message id.  Final query looked like this:

Comment: SELECT m.Person ID FROM Person p  WHERE m.PersonID IN ( SELECT MemberID  FROM PersonMsgResponse pmr WHERE pmr.MessageID = 1 AND pmr.Received = 'N' AND pmr.PersonID NOT IN ( SELECT MemberID FROM PersonMsgResponse pmr WHERE pmrMessageID = 1 AND pmr.Received = 'Y' ) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Person AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM PersonMsgResponse AS pmr
                  WHERE p.Id = pmr.personID AND p.Received = 'Y' AND
                        p.MessageID = 1)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM PersonMsgResponse AS pmr
                  WHERE p.Id = pmr.personID AND p.MessageID = 1)
```

The above query will return a list of persons that did not receive a *specific* message in *any* of the available methods.

Comment: This does not work because it returns persons the message was not sent to.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

You can use a [NOT EXISTS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) subquery:

```
select MsgID, PerID from PersonMsgResponse p1
inner join PersonMsgResponse p3 on p1.MsgID=p3.MsgId and p1.PerID=32.PerID and p3.Received='N'
where not exists(select 1 from PersonMsgResponse p2 where p1.MsgID=p2.MsgId and p1.PerID=p2.PerID and p2.Received='Y')
```

If you want names from the persons table, then just inner join the persons table on p1.

Comment: This does not work because it returns persons the message was not sent to.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   PersonTable.Person
From     Person as PersonTable inner join PersonMsgResponse as ResponseTable 
         on PersonTable.Id = ResponseTable.PerId
where    ResponseTable.Received = 'n'
```

add Distinct to the select statement  as so

```
Select Distinct (PersonTable.Person)
```

If you don't want repeated Persons

**UPDATE**

From your comment, change the value so no person can have a 'y' for received

```
select   Distinct (PersonTable.Id) , PersonTable.Name, ResponseTable.Received
From     Person as PersonTable inner join PersonMsgResponse as ResponseTable 
         on PersonTable.Id = ResponseTable.PerId
where    ResponseTable.Received != 'Y'
```

Comment: This does not work because it returns persons the message was sent to that they opened with another method.